# Ensure SSH-2.0 working rather than SSH-1.5

Tags: ssh

Upon reading the book [Amazon.com: SSH Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1642350028)

It  suggest not to touch SSH-1 and  states that

> The incremental improvements to SSH-1, such as SSH 1.3 and
>   1.5, are vulnerable. SSH servers that offer SSH version 1.99 support SSH
>   version 1 and version 2.
>   Do not let your SSH clients request SSH-1. Do not let your SSH servers offer
>   SSH-1.
>   OpenSSH has removed support for SSH-1, so if you have an old embedded
>   device that only speaks SSH-1, you’ll need to manage it with PuTTY or, better
>   still, spend a couple dollars to replace that device with something built this
>   millennium.
>   SSH-2 is the modern standard. The protocol is designed so that vulnerabilities
>   can be quickly addressed as they are discovered. Our constantly-increasing
>   computing power makes today’s strong encryption tomorrow’s security risk, so
>   SSH-2 is designed so that its algorithms and protocols can be upgraded in place.
>   Protocols such as SCP and SFTP (Chapter 7) are built atop SSH.

Refer to SSH manual

```
me@alpha:~/Documents/OrgMode$ man ssh | tail -5
     OpenSSH is a derivative of the original and free ssh 1.2.12 release by Tatu Ylonen.  Aaron Campbell, Bob
     Beck, Markus Friedl, Niels Provos, Theo de Raadt and Dug Song removed many bugs, re-added newer features
     and created OpenSSH.  Markus Friedl contributed the support for SSH protocol versions 1.5 and 2.0.

BSD                                             February 23, 2018                                            BSD
```

Which indicate to support SSH-1.5

How could I make sure SSH server working on protocol 2.0 on my computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man sshd`:

> ```
> AUTHENTICATION
>      The OpenSSH SSH daemon supports SSH protocols 1 and 2.  The default is to
>      use protocol 2 only, though this can be changed via the Protocol option
>      in sshd_config(5).  Protocol 1 should not be used and is only offered to
>      support legacy devices.
> ```

You can verify how your SSH server is actually configured by looking at its `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
```

You can check what protocols a running SSH server supports by connecting to it using the `ssh` client and using the `-Q` (query) option:

```
$ ssh -Q protocol-version localhost
2
```